# Does updating one field will download the whole document from the database or just update local version?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example the document contains the following structure:

```
{
  fieldA: number,
  fieldB: {
    subFieldA: string,
    subFieldB: string,
  }
}
```

... and is being listened with the onSnapshot method.

```
FirebaseDb
  .collection(`someCollection`).doc('documentAbove')
  .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (snapshot) => {
    // when the document being modified it becomes available at this stage
  })
```

My question is if when the document will be modified will the firestore download it once again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the document will be downloaded again in its entirety while that listener is active, and you will be charged for a read on that document for each change.